# loop for array gives error in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have function like :

```
create or replace function dedup_temp
 return varchar2
 as 
 TYPE OriType IS TABLE OF deduporiginal%ROWTYPE;
 type1 OriType;
 num number;
 begin
 select count(1) into num from deduporiginal;
 select * into type1(num) from deduporiginal where rownum < 125;


   for i in 1 .. type1.count
   loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_month_va(i): '||type1(i).name);
   end loop; 

 return 'DONE';

 end dedup_temp;
```

It compile successfully but gives error while run it with query like

```
 select dedup_temp() from dual;
```

Error :

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "CRESTELDEDUPDEV.DEDUP_TEMP", line 9
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Comment: What should be the return type of function if i want to return type1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select many rows to a plsql table you can use the bulk collect:

```
 select * BULK COLLECT into type1 from deduporiginal where rownum < 125;
```

**update:** if you want to return type1:

I don't think that you can create a type object outside the function that uses %ROWTYPE, so you'll probably have to pack it all into a package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_name IS
  TYPE OriType IS TABLE OF deduporiginal%ROWTYPE;
  FUNCTION dedup_temp RETURN OriType ;
END package_name ;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_name IS
FUNCTION dedup_temp RETURN OriType IS
 type1 OriType;
 num number;
 begin
   select count(1) into num from deduporiginal;
   select * BULK COLLECT into type1 from deduporiginal where rownum < 125;


   for i in 1 .. type1.count
   loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_month_va(i): '||type1(i).name);
   end loop; 

   return type1 ;
 end dedup_temp;

END package_name ;
/
```

but I'm sure you'll be able to use it within a select statment as :

```
 select package_name.dedup_temp() from dual;
```

For doing something like that you need a pipelined function

Comment: `bulk collect` is right, but `type1(num)` is not. it should be `type1` instead.

Comment: thanks @René Nyffenegger, fixed it (I should haved checked what I copy pasted)

Comment: What should be the return type of function if i want to return type1 ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume that the table `deduporiginal` returns more than one row for the condition `rownum < 125`

You probably wanted something like

```
create or replace function dedup_temp  
   return varchar2  
as
   TYPE OriType IS TABLE OF deduporiginal%ROWTYPE;  
   type1 OriType;  num number;  
begin  
  --?   select count(1) into num from deduporiginal;  
  for r in (
       select *   
         from deduporiginal 
         where rownum < 125
  ) loop

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_month_va(i): ' || r.name);  
  end loop; 

  return 'DONE';  

end dedup_temp;
```

Comment: actually i want to return array i.e type1 from this function but before i want to check that is iteration possible on that ?

Comment: If that is what you want why did you ask a completely different question?